# firestore query multiple filter to retrieve collection in react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore query criteria
[image: Firestore query criteria]
Console.log of the query result
[image: Console.log of the query result]
Source code-render data
[image: Source code-render data]
I am new to react native firebase firestore.
I am designing an app where the functionality is that the user should be able to search for a registered user on any of the three critieria:

1. by Name
2. by Expertise
3. by Location

If the user explicitly types in these fields, my code will retrieve the filtered result from firestore

Code in react native to retrieve from firestore:

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
    var routeRef = db.collection("users");
    var queryResult = routeRef
.where(("Name", "==", NameInput)
.where("Expertise", "==", ExpertiseInput)
.where("Location","==" , LocationInput))
.get().then(function(snapshot){/* ... */}
```

Scenario:
If the user did not type in any search criteria in the UI for any one field, say "Location" , in that scenario I dont want to set the filter for that criteria from firestore.
That means , the expected code should be:

```
   var queryResult = routeRef
    .where(("Name", "==", NameInput)
    .where("Expertise", "==", ExpertiseInput)
```

Question:
I am not sure how to dynamically set the .where condition based on the whether user typed in UI or not.
Can anyone please help?

Still this does not get the query result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `where()` function returns a `Query` object (which allows you to query multiple `where()` conditions in the first place). So you can sorta "save the step-by-step progress" conditionally. Something like this:

```js
const routeRef = db.collection("users");
const nameFilter = NameInput ? routeRef.where("Name", "==", NameInput) : routeRef;
const expertiseFilter = ExpertiseInput ? nameFilter.where("Expertise", "==", ExpertiseInput) : nameFilter;
const locationFilter = LocationInput ? expertiseFilter.where("Location", "==", LocationInput) : expertiseFilter;
locationFilter.get().then(snapshot => {
   // The snapshot returned by `where().get()` does not have a `data()` reference since it returns multiple documents, it has `docs` property which is an array of all the documents matched
   snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
     const docData = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
     console.log(docData);
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me try and update you soon

Comment: Jay Codist Thank you

Comment: Jay Codist, I tried however am not getting result. Am not sure what is the cause of this . Please refer to the attached screen shot of the VSS Code . Appreciate your help

Comment: Oh I see what you're doing wrong. Updating my answer @Bhol. Basically, change your `snapshot.forEach()` to `snapshot.docs.forEach()`

Comment: Did you see my comment above?

Comment: Thanks @Jay Codist for the help. I am updating the query now per your feedback. Will update you the result soon.

Comment: Hi @Jay Codist, tried the above solution. However still no luck. The firestore did not fetch any query result.

Comment: Update your question with your new code and the result you're getting

Comment: Hi@ Jay Codist, I have updated the question with the latest 3 screen shots.

Comment: We'll continue the discussion at this chatroom: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219571/discussion-between-bhol-and-jay-codist

Comment: -Thank you so much. This is working fine now.